# I want to hide "sold by" on certain pages with id page 43

Tags: php, filters, shortcode, actions

I want to hide "sold by" on certain pages with id page 43
if I use this code, it's hidden for all pages on my site

```
/  Remove sold by in product loops  /
remove_action ('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', array ('WCV_Vendor_Shop', 'template_loop_sold_by'), 9, 2);
```

how to make a special hidden on the page with id 43
thank you

Comment: currently, where have you put this code?

Comment: in my active theme function.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

if (is_page('43')){
remove_action ('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', array ('WCV_Vendor_Shop', 'template_loop_sold_by'), 9, 2);}

Comment: hi @dan_sutherland
I tried your code but it doesn't work either,
and nothing happened